# python - fastapi - graphene - sql alchemy - not able to query relationship column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, graphene-python

sqlalchemy models

```
class AssetAssignment(base_model.BaseModel, Base):
    __tablename__ = "asset_assignment"

    id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('page_asset.asset_assignment_id'), primary_key=True, index=True, name="id")
    asset_type_id = Column(Integer,nullable=False,name="asset_type_id")
    asset_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('asset.id'), nullable=False,name="asset_id")
    status = Column(Integer, nullable=False, name="status", default=1)
    public=Column(Integer, nullable=True, name="public",default=1)

class Page(Base):
    __tablename__ = "page"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, name="id")
    page_id = Column(Integer,nullable=False,name="page_id")
    asset_assignment_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False,name="asset_assignment_id")
    asset_assignment=relationship("AssetAssignment",lazy='joined',uselist=True)
```

Trying to access the above via graphql:

```
class Asset(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Page
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    all_assets= graphene.List(Asset)
  def resolve_all_assets(self,info):
        query = Asset.get_query(info)  # SQLAlchemy query
        return query.all()
```

The result doesnt have "asset_assignment" field , its a relationship column.

Graphql query

```
{
  allAssets{
   asset_assignment
  }
}
```

Result

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot query field \"asset_assignment\" on type \"Asset\". Did you mean \"assetAssignmentId\"?",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 39,
          "column": 4
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLAlchemyConnectionField helped in obtaining the relationship columns

all_assets= SQLAlchemyConnectionField(Page.connection)